# SQL exclude rows that contain anything other than desired item

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to select rows that only contain desired items, if contain desired item and other items, exclude it.

for example, sample data,

```
Primarykey    food_code           recipes
    1           22             only_rice_5874136489
    2           22             only_rice_9549618454
    3           33             only_rice_5874136489
    4           33             only_peanut_8889548456
    5           44             only_pepper_7777777715
```

food_code =  2 , contain the recipes begin with only_rice, that is what i want, but food_code =3 contain rice and peanut, don't select it, food_code = 44 don't select it too due to not contain rice.

Expected output;

```
Primarykey    food_code           recipes
    1           22             only_rice_5874136489
    2           22             only_rice_9549618454
```

the challenge is i have millions of rows, they all have the same string pattern, only the one set of trailing numbers are different, if write down all items that need to be excluded, e.g.(only_peanut..... only_pepper) is not a good solutions.

Comment: ?"millions of rows" > does this mean that food_code goes from 1 to 2,000,000? What is the largest value in the column food_code?     Also, how can we determine "begin with"?? do all recipes items have some guaranteed pattern?  always two Underscores?  always only one set of trailing numbers after the last Underscore?   The solution is to count how many "begin with"-s there are grouped by "food_code", and select only the count=1 food_codes.  But first we need to have you define these initial requirements a little bit more.

Comment: @donPablo yes, they have similar pattern, only the one set of trailing numbers are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check for `NOT EXISTS` of other item that is NOT `only_rice`

```
SELECT *
FROM   recipes r
WHERE  r.recipes LIKE 'only_rice%'
AND    NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT *
           FROM   recipes x
           WHERE  x.food_code = r.food_code
           AND    x.recipes NOT LIKE 'only_rice%'
       )
```